# Php Exception error thrown

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building this Login system for my website. Everything seemed to work ok until I came across updating user details stored in database. Every time I try to update dummy details I get thrown an Exception and Can't figure out why.

Could You please scan through quickly and help me find an error if there is one? There are no syntax errors.

update.php

```
$user = new User();
            if(!$user->isLoggedIn()){
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            }

            // Check whether token is submited and user exists
            if(Input::exists()){
                if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){

                    $validate = new Validate();
                    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                        'Name' => array(
                            'required' => true,
                            'min' => 4,
                            'max' => 30
                        ),
                        'email' => array(
                            'required' =>true
                        )
                    ));

                    if($validation->passed()){
                        // Update

                        try{
                            $user->update(array(
                                'Name' => Input::get('Name'),
                                'email' => Input::get('email')
                            ));

                Session::flash('home', 'Your details have been updated');
                Redirect::to('index.php');

                        }catch(Exception $e) {
                            die($e->getMessage());
                        }

                    } else {
                        foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
                            echo ('<p>' . $error . '</p>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

User.php class

```
class User{
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_cookieName,
            $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null){
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
        $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');


        if(!$user){
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)){
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                } else {
                    // Process Log out
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }

    public function update($fields = array(), $id = null){

        if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()){
            $id = $this->data()->id;
        }

      if(!$this->_db->update('user', $id, $fields)){
    throw new Exception('Sorry, there was problem updating. Please try again later.');
        }

    }

    public function create($fields = array()){
        if(!$this->_db->insert('user', $fields)){
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating new account.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null){
        if($user){
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'Username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('user', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()){
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function login($Username = null, $password =  null, $remember = false){



        if(!$Username && !$password && $this->exists()){
            // Log User in

            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
        } else {

            $user = $this->find($Username);
            if($user){
                if($this->data()->Password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
                    Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                    if($remember){
                        $hash = Hash::unique();
                        $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                        if(!$hashCheck->count()){
                            $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                                'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                                'hash' => $hash
                            ));
                        } else {
                            $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                        }

                        Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function exists(){
        return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
    }

    public function logout(){

        $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

        Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
        Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
    }

    public function data(){
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(){
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

(**if(!$this->_db->update('user', $id, $fields)){
        throw new Exception('Sorry, there was problem updating. Please try again later.');
            }**)

This is the exception i get.. Thanks a million

If it helps update() is the method I get the error from

This is my DB class:

```
class DB{
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo,
                $_query,
                $_error = false,
                $_results,
                $_count = 0;


        private function __construct(){

            try {
                $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' .
                        Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' .
                        Config::get('mysql/db'),
                        Config::get('mysql/username'),
                        Config::get('mysql/password'));

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e -> getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance(){
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
                self::$_instance = new DB();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        public function query($sql, $params = array()){

            $this->_error = false;

            // Check if query has been prepared properly

            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){

                $x = 1;
                if(count($params)){
                    foreach($params as $param){
                        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                        $x++;
                    }
                }

            // If the query has been prepared successfuly, store the result
                if($this->_query->execute()){
                    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                } else {
                    $this->_error = true;
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }

        public function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
            if(count($where) === 3){
                $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

                $field      = $where[0];
                $operator   = $where[1];
                $value      = $where[2];

                if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
                    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        // QUERYING DATA FROM DATABASE
        public function get($table, $where){
            return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
        }

        // DELETING DATA FROM DATABASE
        public function delete($table, $where){
            return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
        }

        // INSERTING DATA INTO DATABASE
        public function insert($table, $fields = array()){
                $keys = array_keys($fields);
                $values = '';
                $x = 1;

                foreach($fields as $field){
                    $values .= "?";

                    if($x < count($fields)){
                        $values .= ', ';
                    }
                    $x++;
                }

                $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES({$values})";

                if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
                    return true;
                }

            return false;
        }

        public function results(){
            return $this->_results;
        }

        public function update($table, $userID, $fields){
            $set = '';
            $x = 1;

            foreach($fields as $name => $value){
                $set .= "{$name} = ?";

                if($x < count($fields)){
                    $set .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }


            $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE userID = {ID}";

            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public function first(){
            return $this->results()[0];
        }

        public function error(){
            return $this->_error;
        }

        public function count(){
            return $this->_count;
        }

    }
```

Comment: That error message is useless. Try using your DB classes error functionality to get the actual error message.

Comment: Wall of code... But you still don't share your definition of `DB::_update()`, which is the one that returns a false/falsy value... Cut the clutter surrounding it, and add that DB::_update function (and its possible dependencies).

Comment: I'm not being ignorant or anything. I'm still learning php. How do I go about in doing that? Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tried to return the sql you will find that it is not valid, such as:

```
function update($table, $userID, $fields){
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $name => $value){
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";

            if($x < count($fields)){
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }


        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE userID = {ID}";

        return $sql;
    }

echo update('table',1,array('f1'=>'v1','f2'=>'v2','f3'=>'v3','f4'=>'v4'));
```

Results would look like:

```
UPDATE table SET f1 = ?, f2 = ?, f3 = ?, f4 = ? WHERE userID = {ID}
```

so your `ID` is not the actual integer that I passed.

but if you changed your statement to be:

```
//some code
$sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE userID = {$userID}";
return $sql;
```

the result would be:

```
UPDATE table SET f1 = ?, f2 = ?, f3 = ?, f4 = ? WHERE userID = 1
```

Comment: Excellent. Ill try that as soon as I get a minute

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Thanks so much